# Reference a django variable between multiple template tags in html

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

**edited for clarity:**

So I have a list of drinks in my selection drop down. Based on what is selected, I want the webpage to render the ingredients that drink has (which I get can get from my tag function drink_joins).

The first problem is the value for the dropdown is set at the first value, even if the user selects a different one.

```
<select>
{% for drink in drinks %}
<option id="dropdown" value="{{drink.drink_name}}">{{drink.drink_name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

I.E. here `function myFunc(){x = document.getElementById('dropdown').value}` will only get the first element in drinks, no matter what is selected in the dropdown.

The second problem is once that is fixed, how can I pass on that value into my tag, without it being in the for loop? For example, `{{'Margarita'|drink_joins}}` would return the right list but I don't know how to put a variable there instead.

```
<select>
{% for drink in drinks %}
<option id="dropdown" value="{{drink.drink_name}}">{{drink.drink_name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select> 
<p> {{ [needs string of dropdown value] | drink_joins }}</p>
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6XLW.png)

Comment: Why not just have a second `for` loop tag? Are you wanting one `li` for each member of `drinks`? If not, which `drink` should `drink` refer to?

Comment: I don't really understand what your issue is. Is the dropdown rendered like it should? Or do you have an issue with your templatetag? Or is your JavaScript not working as expected?

Comment: `document.getElementById("dropdown").value` will always give you just the selected value, which is the first one if no selection was made by the user.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Hopefully the edit makes it more clear. @JanMalte `document.getElementById("dropdown").value` doesn't seem to give the selected value in this case because the values come from a Django for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id="dropdown"` is set in every `option`, it should be id of `select`. `<select id="dropdown">`

And you can't dynamicly change value for template tag, the are procesed on server while js is on client side.

I sugest using ajax, create view with logic from filter and send request with value from select.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-ajax-request-in-django/